# Why a long running request is freezing my FastAPI server?

Tags: python, asynchronous, fastapi

I'm seeking help to clarify how asynchronous requests work in FastAPI.
I deployed my FastAPI+NGINX+Uvicorn app on a *t2.small* EC2 instance (1 vCPU / 2GiB RAM).

It is a simple proxy server that returns the result for the provided **?url=**

```python
async def proxy(request, sUrl):
    targetResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url=urllib.parse.unquote(sUrl)))
    return Response(
        status_code=targetResponse.status,
        content=targetResponse.read().decode('utf-8'),
        media_type=targetResponse.headers['Content-Type']
        )

@app.get("/")
async def get_proxy(url: str = "", request: Request = {}):
    return await proxy(request, url)
```

If I send a request `myfastapiserver.com/?url=example.com` and if `example.com` is unresponsive, all subsequent requests will have to wait until the initial request times out.

My questions:

1. Why the first request is freezing my server when trying to get data from a 3rd party web service and that web service is not responding?
2. Can I make my server to handle multiple requests no matter how long each one takes?
3. What would be the difference if I had 2 vCPUs instead of 1?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: I don't know FastAPI thoroughly but probably it processes all async calls in the same event loop (in the same thread) and therefore synchronous blocking operations block the whole loop. The synchronous `urllib.request.urlopen` should run in a separate thread or be replaced by an asynchronous alternative from `asyncio` package or an external library.

Comment: `urllib.request` is not an asyncio library. In asyncio, there is only one application thread. In order to allow other work to resume you need calls to `await`. Here, you are making a blocking call to urllib, which does not await. This means that no other coroutines can execute until this is done. Use an async http library like aiohttp https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/

Comment: @MichaelButscher this is correct. Any route defined as async is run on the main scheduler thread, and if the route is synchronous it is offloaded to a threadpool. This logic also applies to dependency resolution in FastAPI. So another solution for OP is to define the route as a regular `def` and not an `async def`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher and @flakes, I will play with `aiohttp` and using `def` instead if `async def`

Answer (score 1):

FastAPI executes all the async endpoints (and dependencies as well) in the same event loop.

Since your `proxy` function is not async (it uses blocking `urllib.request.urlopen`) it blocks event loop and affects the performance of your app.

To avoid this you can either use async alternative of `urllib.request.urlopen` or make all the endpoints which use `proxy` function (and other blocking functions) synchronous:

```
@app.get("/")
def get_proxy(url: str = "", request: Request = {}):
    return await proxy(request, url)
```

In this case, FastAPI will execute this endpoint calls in separate threads, and it will not have such a big impact on your app's performance.

Comment: Thanks @YuriiMotov! Your answer confirms @flakes' recommendation. I will make the endpoint synchronous for now and look into using something like `aiohttp` later.
Appreciate your input!